# How is the set $\emptyset^\emptyset$ defined?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

By $\emptyset^{\large\emptyset}$ i mean the set of functions from $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$.

Is it the empty set or the set containing the empty set?

I just dont know how to prove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set $\emptyset^\emptyset$ contains one and only one element, which is $\emptyset$. For more details, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440458/it-is-posible-to-have-a-function-f-with-the-following-property/2440473#2440473) and its answers.

Comment: So it actually has an element?

Comment: @Garmekain That's what I wrote.

Comment: And so $0^0=1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Nice remark!

Comment: @Garmekain You've already got two great answers, but here's one more comment: remember that formally a function $f\colon A \to B$ is a subset $f \subseteq A \times B$ satisfying certain properties. So $f\colon \varnothing \to \varnothing$ is actually a subset $f \subseteq \varnothing \times \varnothing = \varnothing$, and hence can only possibly be $\varnothing$. Since $\varnothing$ satisfies the properties required to be a function, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Lets approach this problem from a category theory perspective. Since $\textsf{Set}$ is a category, note that it has the following property:

> For every object (set) $A$ of $\textsf{Set}$, there exists (at least)
>   one morphism (function) $1_A \in \text{Hom}_\textsf{Set} (A,A)$, the
>   'identity' on $A$.

Noting that $\emptyset \in \text{Obj($\textsf{Set}$)}$, then the set $\emptyset^\emptyset = \text{Hom}_\textsf{Set} (\emptyset,\emptyset) \neq \emptyset$, that is, it contains at least one function. And yes, that element in $\emptyset^\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$.

Also, never forget the crucial thing you're taught when learning set theory! For every set $A$, $\emptyset \subseteq A$.